# "Unreachable" code error in Eclipse (Android SDK)

Tags: java

I am following a tutorial at the moment by thenewboston. I keep encountering an error with unreachable code with the while loop, which is to constantly check if the holder is true.

*EDIT* This has been solved.

```
    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    Thread ourThread = null;
    boolean isRunning = true;

    public MyBringBackSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
    }

    public void pause(){
        isRunning = false;
        while(true){
            try {
                ourThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        ourThread = null;
    }
    public void resume(){
        isRunning = true;
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(isRunning){
            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid());
                continue;   

                Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas(); //Unreachable code
                canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150);
                ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @SJuan76 Oh oversaw that... deleted the comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do  like this :

```
   if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())   // remove semicolon 
            continue;
```

Comment: Correct. But it is better to also add {}

Comment: ya. agree.but for single line we can do this also.I prefer the brackets for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You really should add more information (which line is the error shown at) but this strikes me as very odd

```
if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid());
   continue;
```

You are doing a conditional that does not execute anything either if true of false. Probably it is something like

```
if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
   continue;
```

Better yet, use brackets, (and, of course, proper indentation)

```
if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
   continue;
}
```

In essence, since the `continue;` was not in the `if` statement, it would execute always. That would exit the loop, making the rest of the loop code useless because it would never get executed. Since the compiler knows that such code is likely the result of a programming error, it throws an error to warn the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrongly formatted. It should read:

```
while(isRunning){
    if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        continue;   // without brackets it's always continue, regardless of the if
    }

    Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas(); //Unreachable code
    canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150);
    ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

Comment: I would take the semi colin out of the conditional

Comment: I agree the code has an incorrect indentation and this makes reading more difficult, but how does that solve the problem?

Comment: It doesn't solve it at all. It just shows where the problem is. I've now also added the obvious solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `;` after `if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())`